# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? (1)

Tags: пунктуация

Твои мысли, неизбежно, приводят ко мне.

Answer (score 3):

Неизбежно - наречие, в предложении выполняет функцию обстоятельства образа действия, вводным словом не является, поэтому обособлять его не нужно.